# Exchange 2016 IIS Modules cafe_exppw / exppw / kerbauth

Tags: iis, exchange, windows-server-2012, iis-8, exchange-2016

A new install of 2016 mailbox role in an existing 2010 Exchange AD environment.

The install didn't complete all the way because there was a typo in the setup command and while troubleshooting kerbauth.dll errors I think I inadvertently messed up one of the cafe_exppw or exppw module locations. If someone could list their modules that are installed for the various exchange sites or know where is is a listing that would be great.      I already tried rebuilding the PowerShell, ECP, OWA, and default site IIS through PowerShell, but the problem persists and I am not able to access the admin panel.

If someone could list their modules that are installed for the various exchange sites or know where is is a listing that would be great.

I already did:

- rejoin PC to domain
- rebuilt ecp and owa
- rebuilt powershell viritual direcotries
- rebuilt EWS backend
- checked all permissions to ensure that the computer account wasnt a domain admin.
- another reinstall as the /RecoverServer option

that fails:

The following server roles are already installed: BridgeheadRole, ClientAccessRole, MailboxRole, UnifiedMessagingRole, FrontendTransportRole, AdminToolsRole, CafeRole.
I just need a listing of the what modules are assigned to the sites and app folders.

I am also getting errors in the event logs:

> Protocol /ecp failed to process request from identity NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Exception: Microsoft.Exchange.Securit
>
> .Authentication.BackendRehydrationException: Rehydration failed. Reason: Source server 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' does not have token serialization permission.

I checked on that error through several links and  made sure that the exchange computer wasn't in the domain admin accts or the other admin areas.

`setup /RecoverServer` option fails:

> The following server roles are already installed: BridgeheadRole, ClientAccessRole, MailboxRole, UnifiedMessagingRole, FrontendTransportRole, AdminToolsRole, CafeRole.

I just need a listing of the what modules are assigned to the IIS site mdodule listing and app folders.

Comment: Its a new server right, so instead of trying to debug something which is broken from the beginning only to hope to get it fixed which might cause issues later didn´t really seamed to be a good way. I would install a new OS and start again.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing .  

I was hoping of just getting the IIS issues fixed quickly instead of doing a full reinstall of the OS and exchange.  

For future reference here is that info taken from the default install:
Due to time restraints, I uninstalled exchange after migrating the system mailboxes (-auditlog, -monitoring, -arbitration, et al) to a temp database in our 2010 server.

Comment: For reference here is the IIS module settings on the default install .

SERVER:
Registered but not active:
-->kerbauth
-->WSMAN
-->exppw
-->cafe_exppw

Active:
none

Default Web Site:
Registerd but not active:
-->kerbauth
-->WSMAN
-->exppw

Default Web Site\Powershell:
Registerd but not active:
-->WSMAN
-->exppw
Active:
-->exppw

Comment: Exchange Back End:
Registerd but not active:
-->kerbauth
-->WSMAN
-->exppw
-->cafe_exppw

Active:
none

Exchange Back End\ECP:
Registerd but not active:
-->kerbauth
-->WSMAN
-->exppw
-->cafe_exppw

Active:
none

Exchange Back End\EWS:
Registerd but not active:
-->kerbauth
-->WSMAN
-->exppw
-->cafe_exppw

Active:
none

Exchange Back End\Powershell:
Registerd but not active:
-->kerbauth
-->exppw
-->cafe_exppw
Active:
-->WSMAN